# Geoserver not buffering external graphic in PointSymbolizer

Tags: geoserver, buffer, sld

We've got some Point data we're displaying in a WMS layer using geoserver 2.2 (same problem on 2.3.1). We style it with the following SLD

```
<Rule>
    <PointSymbolizer>
     <Graphic>
       <ExternalGraphic>
         <OnlineResource
           xlink:type="simple"
           xlink:href="http://server/directory/image.png" />
         <Format>image/png</Format>
       </ExternalGraphic>
       <Size>28</Size>
     </Graphic>
   </PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

The problem is that when I click on the edge of the image displayed, the getFeatureInfo returns nothing. When I click dead-center or near-center, I get my data.
I have checked that the image is indeed 28px by 28px

I have added a buffer parameter to the getFeatureInfo request and that "solves" it but my images are different sizes in other layers so that's not a satisfying solution.

Any idea why geoserver might not be computing the buffer correctly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. I fix the problem by publish again layer and use cycle graphic style and set radius big then graphic icon
2. I use new layer_name above for getfeature only and insert it into "nameGetFeature: new_layer" for your layer to show